# Reverse Linked list

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a linked list with pointers.
I need to reverse the linked list, so I wrote rotate(List &l)
but i don't get the result I expect.
Since input is
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
i would expect 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
as a result, but i get
0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Since I can't find what I did wrong, can you point me at what is incorrect?
the problem seems to start here: (rotate)

```
while(end->next !=0){
       end = end->next;
    }
```

I get there that the first node is the last node (since cout << end->d; gives me0 instead of 9)

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef class Node *List;
struct Node{ 
    int d;
    List next;
};
//update : renamed
void reverse(List &l){
/*
start :
a b c d e

b c d e **a**
c d e **b** a
d e **c** b a
Result:
e **d** c b a
    */

    // get last node
    List end = l;
    while(end->next !=0){
       end = end->next;
    }
    //insert first node directly after the original last node
    while(l!=end){
        List hulp = l;
        l = hulp->next;
        hulp->next = end->next;
        end->next=hulp;
    }
}
int main(){
    List l = new Node();
    int i = 0;
    List k = l;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        k->d = i;
        k->next = new Node();
        k = k->next; 
        i++;
    }
    List m = l;
    while ( m->next !=0 )
    {
        cout << m->d << endl;
        m = m->next;
    }
    reverse(l);
     m = l;
    while ( m->next !=0 )
    {
        cout << m->d << endl;
        m = m->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you reversing the linked list or rotating it?

Comment: I'm reversing it, sorry for wrong name

Comment: Also, I don't understand the steps you describe in your comment that starts "start:".

Comment: To me, a function named `rotate` which "reverses" a list is confusing. I suggest changing the name to `reverse`.

Comment: if you have a, b, c
then i add a behind c, and then b between c and a, so the list is reversed

Comment: Going from "abcde" to "bcdea" makes sense, but how do you get "decba" from there?

Comment: the first character is always inserted after the original last character;<br>
a b c d e<br>

b c d e **a**<br>
c d e **b** a<br>
d e **c** b a<br>
Result:<br>
e **d** c b a

Comment: In a simple linked list where a node has a value and a pointer to the next node, you cannot re-use the pointers. You read the entire linked list from start to finish, remembering the order, and create a new linked list (using malloc as appropriate to create new pointers) in reverse order. You can use recursion to your advantage to create that loop, which when it gets to the last node of the original linked list, starts "popping off" and creating the new linked list in the reverse order. Better still, create a bi-directional linked list, which you can traverse either way.

Comment: chris, I understand your point, but why do i get the strange result "0" when i try to get the last node that should be 9? (//get last node)

Comment: @chris Why can't you reuse the already allocated memory? If it has already been `new`d, your program owns it as long as it wishes to keep it.

Comment: @user1331696 It seems that you have stopped your while loop too early...or else you need to treat the first node as a special case by moving it to the end of the list.

Comment: @chris The OP's "in-place" reverse algorithm trades more space efficiency for less time efficiency. As long as the code doesn't lose track of a pointer to allocated memory and create a memory leak, this is quite acceptable.

Comment: Maybe this will help figure out http://liveworkspace.org/code/3C720T$9

Comment: @Code-Guru, when i replace the part to locate the last part to
while(end->d != 9 ){
           end = end->next;
        }
results are correct, I just tested that, so it seems something is wrong with that thing. You mentionned something about stopping the loop too early, why did I stop the loop too early there?

Comment: @Code-Guru: to "re-use" the pointers means creating a bi-directional linked list from the original. Whilst that would be fine it's not the stated goal of (only) having a reversed list. Otherwise all the pointers need to be changed. This is all do-able in about a ten line recursive loop, instead of the many loops with strange special conditions in the code as is. The code looks very strange indeed. But indeed it would be much simpler for a beginner to just create a brand new linked list in reverse order instead of beating around the bush.

Comment: @chris Granted, doing a reverse which is not "in-place" is doable (and probably more easily doing one "in-place"). I don't see the connection between reusing already allocated memory and creating a b-directional linked list. I also don't see any technical requirements why the list cannot be reversed "in place" by reusing pointers to the memory which the code already owns.

Comment: After our suggestion, I want to make a suggestion that I should have stated at the very beginning. Learning to debug code is a critical skill for any programmer. A C programmer has two primary tools for this: adding `printf()` statments throughout their code and using a source-level debugger.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a typical way of iterating through a linked list:

```
while (m->next != 0) {
    cout << m->d << endl;
    m = m->next;
}
```

Instead, you should do:

```
while (m != 0) {
    cout << m->d << endl;
    m = m->next;
}
```

If you do this, you'll see that the linked list you initially created is actually:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0
```

Your Printing logic then prints it as:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Your reverse then likely functions correctly, producing a list of:

```
0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
```

Which you print as:

```
0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly initialized the list. The last node with d=9, it should have a null `next`, but it actually has a `new Node`. To fix that, change you list initialization to:

```
for (int i = 0; ; ++i)
{
    k->d = i;
    if (i >= 9) {
        break;
    }
    k->next = new Node();
    k = k->next; 
}
```

After changing that, you also need change your initial AND final printing(otherwise you won't print the last node). The print code should be(you'd better put it into a print function to avoid duplicate code):

```
for ( ; m; m = m->next)
{
    cout << m->d << endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, these two mistakes cost me quite some time, but at least I understand now why it didn't work. Thanks alot!